# How to perform solution migration between evironments?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

We have a large solution that we are trying to import into another one of our Dynamics 365 online environments. However, the solution is missing around 3 pages worth of required components when we try to export it. If we try to add the required components through the "Add required components" button in the solution, then we can only do it 1 record at a time. This would take a very long time to do. Is there a better way to import these required components? If not, what is recommended in this situation and what are some best practices for managing solutions in a Dev -> Test -> Prod environment scenario?

Answer (score 0):

There are so many reasons why a solution might fail on import, and even more "best practices" for pushing a solution from DEV to TEST to PROD.

Firstly, always make sure that each of your environments is as close to the same as possible.  What do I mean by this?  Mainly, make sure the managed solutions from each environment match up.  Many times, dependencies are pulled in from managed solutions due to bad solution design.  WHich brings me to...

Secondly - when you are adding components (entities) to your solution, are you clicking the "add all assets" button?  If so - stop doing this.  There is no need to pull in 'all assets' on ANY OOB CRM entities.  Of course, a custom entity, you may want to pull in all assets.  But say you're pulling the Contact entity into your solution, to build a few new fields and customize a form.  Instead of all assets, just bring in the shell of account (no assets selected).  If you want to clone a form, and make changes, include that form ONLY, then open it and save as, and you will have it in your solution.  If you "add all assets", then you're bringing in every relationship in the Contact entity, which is typically where your dependencies will go wonky.  Only include those assets you truly need - and always try to avoid including OOB relationships.

In the long run, there is no 'short way' or quick way, to identify and fix your dependencies.  What I typically do is take a few screenshots, and go through them 1 by 1 and resolve them.  The error should tell you what artifact is causing the error, and which element requires that artifact.  You have to resolve each of these, and then re-attempt the import.

If you post some screens, Ill try to help you resolve the issues.